# Datatables How Can I hide Column if data is null

Tags: laravel, datatables, laravel-8

```
 columns: [
                {data: 'debit_1', name: 'debit_1'},
                {data: 'credit_1', name: 'credit_1'},
                {data: 'debit_2', name: 'debit_2'},
                {data: 'credit_2', name: 'credit_2'},
                {data: 'debit_3', name: 'debit_3'},
                {data: 'credit_3', name: 'credit_3'},
         
            ],          
            columnDefs: [
                {width: 300, targets: 2},
                {
                    "targets": [0,1,2,3,4,5],
                    render: function (data, type, row){
                      if(data === null){
                            return '<th style="display:none;"></th>';
                        }
                  }
                },                
            ],
```

when there is data is null I want to hide the columns in the datatable. can anyone help me ?

Comment: You want to hide the entire column? Or just the cell data?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in multiple ways, I'm writing down some of them.

```
columnDefs: [
    { width: 300, targets: 2},
    {
        "targets": [0,1,2,3,4,5],
        render: function (data, type, row) {
            if(data == null) {
                table.columns([column_number]).visible(false);
            }
            else {
                '<text>' + data + '</text>';
            }
        }
    },                
],
```

OR

```
"initComplete": function(settings, json) {
    if (json.column_name == null) {
       table.column([column_number]).visible(false);
    }
 }
```

Note : These are just hints, you need to edit code in according to your need.